# Bash script runs from Terminal but not from LaunchD

Tags: mysql, bash, launchd, osx-server, launch-daemon

I have a script that runs a mysqldump and then a mysql insert from bash. It works fine from terminal, even as root (which I believe LaunchD runs as) but it will not run the mysql insert from launchd, but will run the mysqldump.

Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -pmypass my_db | gzip -9 > /path/to/dump.sql.gz
mysql -u root -pmypass my_db2 < /path/to/insert.sql
```

and my com.me.BackupThing.plist (from /Library/LaunchAgents), which does run and executes all but the mysql command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.BackupThing</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/full/path/to/above/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>QueueDirectories</key>
    <array/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>01</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>administrator</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

All runs from terminal as root, and mysql's bin is exported on roots command path.

Why would it ignore the mysql command from launchd?

**EDIT**

Thanks to arco444 for solution, full path was required on mysql for some reason, new script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -pmypass my_db | gzip -9 > /path/to/dump.sql.gz
/path/to/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -pmypass my_db2 < /path/to/insert.sql
```

Comment: launchd can fail to pick up environment variables that are present in a shell. Where is the mysql binary? Does it work if you specify the full path?

Comment: It's in /usr/local/mysql/bin ... same place as the mysqldump command. Surely if that were true then it wouldn't be able to run that either?

Comment: Hey you were right @arco444, full path, and away! Mysqldump must be aliased somewhere, but mysql mustn't have been. Strange. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: you may want to have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/a/13210563/1578528